# Except Developers,Admin and Tester rest of the users not able to use APP

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I want to user Facebook App in my Websites functionality.

When user clicks on Lgin with facebook button user should be able to login. Once the user will lgoin using fb credentials he/she will get permission page for App. and once he clicks "Okay/Puiblish" user will get one more button.

So using the FB session I do fetch users content and trying to show them.

Issue : Log in is working and also I am getting permission page for all the users.
But when I try to click on another button, it gives me alert message(For All users except App admin,developer,tester).

I feel there is some problem with App configuration. Which is working properly for APP admin,developer and tester account.

Is there any one knowing about such issue and how can I resolve this? It will be a helping hand for me.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: what alert message would that be?

Comment: Alert Message: "Sorry, Your friend won't let us look through thier profile"

It is coming from my code as it not fulfilling the condition for getting "user_photos".
In my Facebook App it is under review.